# Adding tooltip inside <td> element using css and overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

basically, I'm having issues displaying a tooltip inside a `<td>` element that has the `overflow hidden` property. The tooltip text class will pop up on hover, but it's cut off due to `overflow hidden`. The parent (div) must have the `relative` position and the child (tooltip) must have the `absolute` position, this is because it needs to be dynamic as every td needs to have it's own tooltip (popping up next to it). Fyi, the text is populated via a json string).

I've seen a lot of examples online, but I don't think they include a **`<td>` solution with overflow hidden and tooltip**.

Any help will be great, thanks.

I have this html/css structure:

```css
.advice-given-class {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.advice-given-class .tooltiptext {
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 240px;
  line-height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
}

.advice-given-class:hover .tooltiptext {
  display: inline;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #DCA;
  background: #444;
  -moz-border-radius: 11px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
  border-radius: 11px;
}

.tooltiptext:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-color: #444 transparent transparent transparent;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <div class="advice-given-class">
    texttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttexttext
    <span class="tooltiptext">
          text from json string
        </span>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: I believe this sort of issue specifically is why many tooltip libraries have an option to append the tooltip to the end of the `<body/>` element rather than adjacent to the content that is triggering it...

Answer (score 0):

you can use

- `position: fixed;` to break overflow rule
- `margin-top : negative height of element` to up the tooltip above element

```css
#bigarea {
  height: 120px;
}

table {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.advice-given-class {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.advice-given-class .tooltiptext {
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  width: 240px;
  line-height: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 15px;
}

.advice-given-class:hover .tooltiptext {
  display: inline;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #DCA;
  background: #444;
  -moz-border-radius: 11px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
  border-radius: 11px;
}

.tooltiptext:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-color: #444 transparent transparent transparent;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigarea"></div>
<table>
  <td>
    <div class="advice-given-class">
      texttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttexttext
      <span class="tooltiptext">
              text from json string
            </span>
    </div>
  </td>
</table>
```